# buffering during authentication

Tags: authentication, go

In this book [enter link description here](https://github.com/astaxie/build-web-application-with-golang/blob/master/en/eBook/14.4.md) on building web applications with Go, it demonstrates how to create custom authentication. Part of the registration function uses this code

```
md5Password := md5.New()
io.WriteString(md5Password, password)
buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
fmt.Fprintf(buffer, "%x", md5Password.Sum(nil))
newPass := buffer.String()
```

which is basically repeated in the login function

```
md5Password := md5.New()
io.WriteString(md5Password, password)
buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
fmt.Fprintf(buffer, "%x", md5Password.Sum(nil))
newPass := buffer.String()
```

What is happening with the buffering in the last 4 lines of the code? Why is it important and how does buffering achieve it?

Comment: that might be an example of using md5, but *please don't use this for real password handling*

Comment: Just to echo this - **please don't use MD5 for hashing passwords**, ever. In fact, I don't even think it should be used as an example because Go's lovely [bcrypt package](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/bcrypt) is just as simple.

Comment: @elithrar thanks, would the example be the same with bcrypt? the package doesn't say much about how to use it

Comment: The guide you're following is (IMO) of extremely poor quality and is not a good basis to learn from. The (older, but still functional) stuff at http://shadynasty.biz/blog/categories/go/ is much better.

Comment: I've filed an issue on the "e-book" with what needs to be fixed: https://github.com/astaxie/build-web-application-with-golang/issues/354 - specifically, you just use `bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password-from-registration-form-here), 12)` and `bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(hash-from-database, []byte(password-from-login-form-here))`. I'm in the process of writing an article on how to do this, but am lacking for time to finish it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the point of that, however that can be replaced by :

```
md5Password := md5.New()
io.WriteString(md5Password, password)
newPass := fmt.Sprintf("%x", md5Password.Sum(nil))
```

The original book might be outdated, but there's absolutely no need for that extra `bytes.Buffer` step.